# I can't install LightRead in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation, 16.04, lightread

I used these commands to install `lightread` application. But is says `unable to locate the package`. How can I install `lightread`. Am I missing something..?

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cooperjona/lightread
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lightread
```

If lightread is not supported in Ubuntu 16.04, please tell me some good alternatives for RSS feed read.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to install `lightread` is to check out the source from launchpad and then create your own package on `quantal` using quickly:

```
bzr branch lp:lightread
cd lightread
quickly package --extras
sudo dpkg -i ../lighread-`version`.deb
```

I don't know what the version quickly will spit out, so you'll have to check.

**Note:** You need to install the `bzr` and `quickly` packages, to download and install the source this way.